# Removing duplicates from a list of dictionaries in Python using deepcopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a list of dictonaries:

```py
list_1 = [{'account': '1234', 'email' : 'abc@xyz.com'}, ... , ...]
```

I wanted to remove the entries with duplicate emails in the list.

```py
import copy
list_2 = copy.deepcopy(list_1)
for i in mainList
 for j in range(len(list_2)-1, -1, -1):
   if ((list_2[j]["email"] == mainList[i])):
                    list_1.remove(list1[j])
```

`mainList` here is the list of emails with which I am comparing values.
`mainList` looks like this:

```py
['abc@xyz.com', 'efg@cvb.com, ..., ...]
```

The main problem is `list_1` is not coming out correctly. If I use list, slicing or even list comprehension to copy it, it will come out empty.
The final result should give `list_1` containing only one element/list/dictionary for each email.
Using copy or deepcopy at least gives me something. It also seems like sometimes I am getting an indexing error.
Using `for x in list_2:` instead returns `list_1` with only one item.
The closest I got to the correct answer was iterating over `list_1` itself while removing items, but it was not 100% correct.

Comment: thats not a list of lists, thats a list of dictionaries.

Comment: In that case, how do I approach my problem? @VishalSingh

Comment: What is `mainList`?

Comment: how do you want your end results to look like?

Comment: @C.Nivs it is a list containing the emails.

Comment: @C.Nivs I have updated the answer to show what mainlist looks like.

Comment: @VishalSingh, the end result should give list_1 containing only one element/list/dictonary for each email.

Comment: which one should the result include if there are multiple dictionaries with same email?

Comment: the first one in list_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate over your list of dictionaries and keep saving every email in a new dictionary only if it is not already present.

```
temp = dict()
list_1 = [{'account': '1234', 'email': 'abc@xyz.com'}]
for d in list_1:
    if d['email'] in temp:
        continue
    else:
        temp[d['email']] = d
final_list = list(temp.values())
```

Comment: temp could be a simple list instead of a dict

Comment: @Antwane but then i would need `set` to remove duplicate emails and also the `in` check in `list` is not O(1).

Comment: @VishalSingh where does mainList (list of emails) come here in the play?

Comment: @jmrjmr It is not clear in the post that you want only the email or the whole dictionary in your final list.

Comment: I do want the whole dictonary, but I am compraring the 'email' with the 'emails' in the mainList. @VishalSingh

Comment: @jmrjmr but you've not clearly explained in the post how you're comparing. Do you want the emails in `Mainlist` to be removed? What to do with emails not present in `Mainlist`?

Comment: @VishalSingh, this one works. I misunderstood. Have a great day! I am marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to remove duplicate dictionaries. Please mention the duplicate dictionaries also in the problem.

```
di = [{'account': '1234', 'email' : 'abc@xyz.com'}, {'account1': '12345', 
'email1' : 'abcd@xyz.com'}, {'account': '1234', 'email' : 'abc@xyz.com'}]
s=[i for n, i in enumerate(d) if i not in di[n + 1:]]
Print(s)
```

This would give you required output

```
[{'account1': '12345', 'email1': 'abcd@xyz.com'}, {'account': '1234', 'email': 
'abc@xyz.com'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I feel to accomplish this is to create an indexed version of `list_1` (a dictionary) based on your key.

```
list_1 = [
    {'account': '1234', 'email' : 'abc@xyz.com'},
    {'account': '1234', 'email' : 'abc@xyz.com'},
    {'account': '4321', 'email' : 'zzz@xyz.com'},
]

list_1_indexed = {}
for row in list_1:
    list_1_indexed.setdefault(row['email'], row)
list_2 = list(list_1_indexed.values())

print(list_2)
```

This will give you:

```
[
    {'account': '1234', 'email': 'abc@xyz.com'},
    {'account': '4321', 'email': 'zzz@xyz.com'}
]
```

I'm not sure I would recommend it, but if you wanted to use a comprehension you might do:

```
list_2 = list({row['email']: row for row in list_1}.values())
```

Note that the first strategy results in the first key row wins and the comprehension the last key row wins.